# Failed GET Request From admin.php To Fetch .min.js File From Unminifed Directory

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, paths

I'm just trying to track down which plugin is making a request for this asset. I'm working with a fresh install of WordPress, Astra theme 2.4.0 and the same version of the Astra Pro plugin, then the current version of Elementor basic, and LifterLMS.

This is the incorrect path in question: https://thewebsitedotcom/wp-content/plugins/astra-addon/addons/lifterlms/assets/js/unminified/lifterlms-builder-settings.min.js?ver=2.4.0

I see that the asset needed is in the Astra Pro plugin, since if I copy/paste the link in the browser, remove the 'un' in unminified, I get the minified file. Likewise, if I just remove the '.min' portion of the js file name, I get the unminified back. So an error was made in writing this path.

It says the asset failed to load at admin.php:2795:1, right in wp-admin. So I'm assuming admin.php is just including files that it needs from other plugins and whatnot in the install? What I'm trying to figure out is which software in this install is requesting the asset through admin.php? Is this a simple answer that I should know?

Sorry, I normally do general full stack dev work with JS and PHP, with some WordPress sprinkled in there. Sometimes it feels like theses little issues like an incorrect path can be so difficult to solve because of all the different pieces working in WordPress.

Thanks for any help you can offer. I will promptly supply any screenshots, dumps, logs, whatever needed to make this easier to fix.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly I believe the error may be with the Astra theme or Astra Pro plugin - and probably not something you can or should correct yourself - instead you should open a ticket/contact the Astra dev team, because if you're having this issue it's likely other users are as well.  What you're looking at is that the Astra AddOn plugin is enqueuing that script in wp-admin, in all areas I guess (not best practice IMO) or, because these plugins look like they're dependencies, the main Astra Builder or the LifterLMS plugin may be calling for the script.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Ok, that's kind of where my mind was at on this, the script being loaded as a dependency, and someone else is calling it, but I'm just not sure the best way to tell who's asking for it. I did open a ticket with the Astra Pro team. I just want to correct in the time being, as I figure an update to fix it should overwrite whatever I do manually. But that's just my thought.

Comment: Whichever plugin it is that's calling it, you won't be able to modify it because if you do you'll nullify the update process, right.  So you end up stuck with a plugin you've modified yourself that can't be updated, or you're stuck waiting for one of the plugin authors to push the fix. It's frustrating.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Ok, gotcha...hmmm. Maybe a code snippet that I can add on to bandage it for the time being, and then just deactivate it once the actual update is in place? Is that a common practice with things like this, since these fixes are so dependent upon the authors?

Comment: If you can get your hands on the correct file, put it into your child theme, you could theoretically de-register the one that's failing and then just enqueue the correct version instead.  Are you using a child theme?  So you'd do this first: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/

Then you'd enqueue the corrected/fixed version: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Then, whenever there's an update to one of the plugins, you could comment out your code, see if the error has been addressed, and if not, uncomment your code.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Sounds like a great place to start. I went back and forth on the child theme thing. I opted not to, because I wasn't modifying any core pieces. I was just using plugins to change anything I wanted, so nothing was actually ever changed. But, for this, a child theme seems to be a solid option. Thanks for the recommendation!